# Is true that $ \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (|X_n|^p) = (\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|X_n|)^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

I am a worker and I am trying to understand a longer proof. In particular I know that $X$ is a stochastic process $\{X_n \}_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$, and I know that $X\in L^p$ (maybe this is unnecessary).
I would like to show that for each $p>0$:
$$ \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (|X_n|^p) = (\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|X_n|)^p.$$
My attempt:

I know that $p >0$, (note that $|X_n|\ge 0$ so the term $ (|X_n|)^p$ is well defined); I get:$
 |X_n| \le \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|X_n| := K$, then, $|X_n|^p \le K^p $ the right side of this inequality does not depend on $n$ hence Iconclude that:
\begin{equation}
\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (|X_n|^p)  \le \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} K^p = K^p = (\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|X_n|)^p.
\end{equation}
Hence:
\begin{equation}
 \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (|X_n|^p) \le (\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|X_n|)^p \;\;\; \forall p>0.
\end{equation}
On the other hand I can use the inequality just proved and write:
\begin{equation}
 \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (|X_n|^p)= \{[\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (|X_n|^p)]^{\frac{1}{p}}\}^p \ge [\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (|X_n|^{p\cdot\frac{1}{p}} )]^p=[\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (|X_n| )]^p .
\end{equation}

Is this correct? I am not self confident. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my strange question... why is it important for the question that *you're a worker*?

Comment: In the sense that it is not an homework and in in the sense that I am not self confident as I was a student.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net; any suggestion for my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in the right direction.

Here is another (fill in the why?s) that is a little more direct solution.

- Notice that $f(x)=x^p$ and $g(x)=x^{1/p}$, $p>0$, are  increasing functions on $[0,\infty)$.
- As $|X_n|\leq\sup_m|X_m|$, one has that $|X_n|^p\leq (\sup_m|X_m|)^p$ (**why?** )which means that $$\sup_n(|X_n|^p)\leq (\sup_n|X_n|)^p$$
- Conversely, since $|X_n|^p\leq(\sup_m|X_m|^p)$, we have |$X_n|\leq (\sup_m|X_m|^p)^{1/p}$ (**why?**) and so, $\sup_n|X_n|\leq (\sup_m|X_m|^p)^{1/p}$.
  Consequently (**why?**)
  $$(\sup_m|X_n|)^p\leq (\sup_n|X_n|^p)$$

Comment: First why: I think that it is true since $f(x)$ is an increasing function;

Comment: second why:  I can apply the function $g(x)$ on both side of the inequality without change the direction of inequality since $g(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: Third why: as the second but  I apply $f(x)$

Comment: These proof, if I get it, is far more elegant than mine.. Do you think that mine is correct, even if too long?

Comment: I got it... thank you very much.